# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4^n}{1+7^n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> $$a_n=\frac{{4}^n}{1+7^n}\\ $$
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\quad ?\quad$$

I know it converges but I am getting thrown off by the use of $n$ as an exponent. What do I do in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write your term in the form
$$\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{7^n}}$$

Comment: So maybe Im just not getting it but I got my answer to be 1. This was wrong. Any more hints?

Comment: the correct answer is $0$

Answer (score 3):

Write it as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(4/7)^n}{7^{-n}+1}$$ so that you can calculate it by putting in the relevant known limits.